# Can I use jQuery to exclude text withing <small> in a string?

Tags: jquery

I have the HTML like the following:

```
<li id="home">
<a data-href="/C">X<br>
<small>Y</small></a>
</li>
```

I am using the following JQuery to extract the contents of the link

```
a = li.parent().parent().children("a, span:not('.toggle')");
a.html();
```

This works however I want to exclude the text inside of the `<small> ... </small>`

Is this possible with JQuery? I know the library is good but I am not sure how I can do something like this.

Comment: When you have to use more than one `parent()`, consider using `closest()` or `parents()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html` needs a parameter `''` to remove the text. Like `a.html('');`
You can use `empty` too. `a.empty();`

The code above will remove everything inside `a`, if you want to remove only what's inside `small` use `find` before.
`a.find('small').empty();`

Comment: Thanks. Should I still use a.html() before this also? Could I use a.html().find('small').empty(); ?

Comment: @Anne When you use `html` you'll replace all selector content with what's passed as parameter. So use one or other.

Comment: @Anne I suggest you to se `empty` because it's faster.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann it'll leave empty `<small></small>` tags inside the code. I suggest using `.remove()`.

Comment: @tpaksu `I want to exclude the text inside of the <small>`. That's what is being asked. So empty do it. If you use `remove`, you'll remove `small` too.